# Put a HTML helper next to a Label

Tags: html, css, layout

I know nothing when it comes to HTML I have a page with Labels, Textboxes and Dropbox's. I have this code

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6">
    <label for="JobLineJob_StatusId">Status:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobLineJob.StatusId, Model.JobLineStatusList, "-- Select One --")
</div>
```

When I go to my page is Has this layout (I cant put pictures because I lack the points according to stack overflow)

> Status:
>
> (Drop Down List)

I don't want the Drop Down List to fall under the Label I want it to be to the right of the label and in line with it like this.

> Status: (Drop Down List)

I've tried writing the code like this

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6">
    <label for="JobLineJob_StatusId">Status: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobLineJob.StatusId, Model.JobLineStatusList, "-- Select One --")</label>                        
</div>
```

and I've tried a few other things as well but everything that didn't result in a error gave me the same layout as the original code. I also don't know about css so I have no clue how to screw with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using Bootstrap, I would simply add another row/columns inside your current column.

It would look something like this:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="JobLineJob_StatusId">Status:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobLineJob.StatusId, Model.JobLineStatusList, "-- Select One --")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This approach should also work well for responsive... the 2 columns will stack on mobile devices, if you don't want that then change them to `col-xs-6` each

Comment: It solved the Textbox/Dropbox under the Label problem. Now I just gotta resize the box so it's the same size as the label text  -_- Thanks

Comment: instead of `col-sm-6` for both you can do something like `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9`, as long as both number add up to 12